# How to find the general solution for the following sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following set of data.Suppose n=16,n is even. and i have to choose my domain all even number upto n-2, the range is given for each value. For n/2 its is know as.  $$f(\frac{n}{2})=\frac{n(n+2)}{4}.$$ The general formula seems to be $$\frac{n(n+2)}{4}-2k.$$ How to calculate this formula
 $$~~Domain:~~2~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 4~~~~~~~~~~~~~6 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~8 ~~~~~~~~~~10~~~~~~~~~~12~~~~~~~~~~14$$

$$Range~~:66~~~~~~~~~~~~68~~~~~~~~~~70~~~~~~~~~~~~72~~~~~~~~~~70~~~~~~~~~~68~~~~~~~~66$$

Answer (score 0):

The left part, with $x \in [2,8]$ seems to be given by $f(x) = 64+x$ while with $x \in [8,14]$, we seem to get $f(x) = 80 - x$.

If you would like to unite both branches in one expression, you can write
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
64 + x, & x \le 8\\
80 - x, & x \ge 8
\end{cases}
 = 72 - |x-8|.
$$

Comment: @gt6989b.ok. But if i want to calculate for large n, n is even, then what will be the form?. here is very specific i wrote.

Comment: @AbdulHameed If the extrapolation is similar, use the final form in the answer, $f(x) = 72-|x-8|$.